# Hiveserver2 cannot fetch result of a query from remote connection

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, mapreduce, hive

Hi I am facing a problem while trying to fetch data from a remote hadoop cluster using hiveserver2.

The JDBC connection is working in the sense that meta data queries such as `show tables` is working and even the queries that require simple listing of data such as `select * from table` is also working.But when a query,that causes a map-reduce job on hadoop,is execute such as `select count(*) from table` then it throws a connection exception.I can see in the hive logs that the query is executed without any error.

I tried the same thing with beeline and it worked when i connected using `localhost` but when I connected using server name the execution just hung.

I am sure I have some configuration property that is causing this problem.

I am using hadoop version 2.0 and Hive version 0.12.0

Just for the sake of clarity the error thrown at the client side is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException:   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:203)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:300)
at com.nanobi.contentserver.Aatest.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:57)
```

Like I said there is no error on the server or hive.log and query is executed successfully.
Best guess is that error is thrown while fetching the result of the query.Can`t find exactly where though.

Please let me know if further clarification is required to understand the problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running the query through Beeline? If not, what? Also, which version of Thrift do you have installed locally?

Comment: Hi Eli,the query is working fine from beeline,while using either "localhost" or IP of the server in the connection url.Even java client works when executed from the server where the Hive is installed.The problem is only while making the remote connection and even then I can see on the Hiveserver2 console that the query is executed without any error,nothing in the logs either.

Comment: Its just that the Hiveserver2 is not able to fetch the result of the query.The issue is seen only in the case of query that causes mapreduce job on hadoop such as 'select count(*) from table'.Simple queries data is fetched by hive server.The Thrift comes with Hive-0.12.0 installation so I am guessing Thrift is of same version as well.Please let me know if you need any other details.Regards

Comment: To be clear do MR-producing queries work when executed from Beeline remotely as well? Or just locally? Anyway, if you've only tried doing things remotely with one library, try another. Pyhs2 (https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2) is easy to use and works quite well. Try there and see if the same issue pops up. Idea is to see if this is something with one of your Java packages, or a system thing.

Comment: executing MR-producing queries form the beeline remotely did not work as well

Comment: This strongly sounds like a version mismatch somewhere to me. Did you try with pyhs2? Anyway, Hive-0.12.0 differs between Apache and CDH2 distributions, for example. Ensure you are using the *exact same* versions for Hive, Hadoop, and Thrift.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are able to fetch data it means your connection with have works fine. Start the hive server again, and check.

If this does'nt work check your hadoop configuration properties.

As you said, "I tried the same thing with beeline and it worked when i connected using localhost but when I connected using server name the execution just hung.", Check whether the Host name is being reflected or not.

Where are you using the JDBC connection to connect to hive server?

Answer (score 0):

Start Hive Server2 first..

> hive --service hiveserver &